# workflow on Kubernetes node

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml, workflow, kubectl

Team, my yaml syntax is correct as I validated it online. However, I am not able to run it and every time it throws a different error.

```
└─ $ ▶ kubectl create -f ~/waste/wf.yaml
Error: failed to parse yaml file: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: unknown field "\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0completions" in workflow.WorkflowDefinition

└─ $ ▶ kubectl create -f ~/waste/wf.yaml
Error: failed to parse yaml file: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: unknown field "\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0mountPath" in workflow.WorkflowDefinition

└─ $ ▶ kubectl create -f ~/waste/wf.yaml
Error: failed to parse yaml file: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: unknown field "\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0- name" in workflow.WorkflowDefinition
```

Any hint what this indicates?

Comment: Can you please share the yaml?

Answer (score 1):

0xA0 (decimal 160) is a white space looking character but is not actually space (0x20 or decimal 32). You have probably copy pasted that from a web page. Fix your yaml to use spaces instead.

"Spaces" in your file: " ”

Actual space: " "

Comment: I actually had that file in utf format.. I converted it to ASCII and all worked.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had that file in utf format.. I converted it to ASCII and all worked.